# Conversion between entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have a question regarding symfony2. I've got a collection of entities and I want to somehow transform it into a collection holding other type of entities. What's supposedly the best way to that? I know that I could make a simple loop, place it in the controller and be over it, but I know that it's not the right way to do it.

With forms we have DataTransformers which handle that kind of problem, but what can I do outside of that? What's the proper way to do it?

I have to convert Material into MaterialJournalItem. Didn't bother to add the php code, because that's shorter, and still represents the same thing.

```
R34\StockServiceBundle\Entity\Material:
    type: entity
    table: material
    repositoryClass: R34\StockServiceBundle\Entity\MaterialRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        unit:
            type: string
            length: 16
        quantity:
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
        lowerLimit:
            column: lower_limit
            type: integer
        price:
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
        bookingAmount:
            column: booking_amount
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
      materialCategory:
        targetEntity: R34\StockServiceBundle\Entity\MaterialCategory
        inversedBy: materials
        joinColumn:
          name: material_category_id
          referencedColumnName: id

R34\StockServiceBundle\Entity\MaterialJournalItem:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: R34\StockServiceBundle\Entity\MaterialJournalItemRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        category:
            type: string
            length: 255
        quantity:
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
        unit:
            type: string
            length: '16'
        price:
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
      materialJournal:
        targetEntity: R34\StockServiceBundle\Entity\MaterialJournal
        inversedBy: materials
        joinColumn:
          name: material_journal_id
          referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well. I'm pulling a collection of materials from the database. Then, after a little of processing I need to persist that to another table. Thus, I need to somehow rewrite the data from one type of entity to another.

Comment: Can you show the entity classes please?  Explain which entity needs to be converted to which, and the data that needs to be carried over.

Comment: Added the code. Fields that need to be carried over have to same name, so it should be obvious. Also, the category relation needs to be reduced and saved as a string. MaterialCategory has just one field.

Comment: Try parsing the original to the copy's constructor.  There would be a suitable place to make the conversion.  You won't be able to find an all-round solution to this as the requirements are inevitably unique to the case.